# Exclude list from another list of documents in Firestore - Swift

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections in `Firestore`:

In the first I have the "alreadyLoaded" user ids,

In the second I have all userIDs,

How can I exclude the fist elements from the second elements making a query in Firestore?

the goal is to get only users that I haven't already loaded (optionally paginating the results).

Is there an easy way to achieve this using Firestore?

EDIT:
The number of documents I'm talking about will eventually become huge

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using a single query at scale.  The only way to solve this situation as you've described is to fully query both collections, then write code in the client to remove the documents from the first set of results using the documents in the second set of results.

In fact, it's not possible to involve two collections in the same query at the same time.  There are no joins.  The only way to exclude documents from a query is to use a [filter](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#query_operators) on the contents of the documents in the single collection.

Firestore might not be the best database for this kind of requirement if the collections are large and you're not able to precompute or cache the results.

Comment: Okay, I got what you're saying, the idea I'm trying to implement is I have a set of cards (such as on Tinder) and whenever a new card is loaded I send the card uid to the database as "already swiped", When I want then to upload more cards I want to exclude the cards already swiped by the user, so I query all the card uids already swiped and exclude them for the query. Are you saying that using Firestore the ONLY option I have is to get all the users firsthand and take out the ones already swiped? It seems so costly in terms of reads. I'm trying to find a solution to this problem

Comment: I hope to have explained myself correctly

Comment: After reading all that, I don't have anything to change in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, so it’s impossible to implement a Tinder like feature using Firestore ... honestly I feel afflicted after having built all of my project with this db.